# Change the default PDF reader programmatically?

Tags: javascript, c#, c#-4.0, operating-system, adobe

If it is possible to programmatically change the default PDF reader in Windows.

*For example*,

If the default reader was "**Foxit**" in my machine, But I need to change my default reader app to "**Adobe**" in c# or javascript.
I have search in many ways. but I do not get an solution.

Is this possible. Please suggest your answers.

Comment: While you can probably do this, you're likely to annoy your users by messing with their settings.

Comment: the default program settings would be stored in the computer registry...this would mean your program is going to have to edit registry :)
[Just something that might help](https://superuser.com/questions/436939/where-is-the-default-program-associations-stored-in-the-registry)

Comment: I am not able to clear in above link. Can you please let me know whether is it  possible to change system's default PDF reader using Registry key? If so please explain with code. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

If your application has administrator privileges you can use something like the following:

```
public enum Readers
{
    AdobeReader = 0,
    FoxitReader = 1
}

Dictionary<int, string> _PDFReaders = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 0,"AcroExch.Document.DC" },
    { 1, "FoxitReader.Document" }
};

public void SetPDFDefault(Readers program)
{
    string nVal = _PDFReaders[(int)program];
    Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf\UserChoice",
        "ProgId", nVal,RegistryValueKind.String);
}
```

Then you can use `SetPDFDefault(Readers.AdobeReader);` to change the default.

EDIT:

You may need to change the permissions on the registry value - to do this run regedit, navigate to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.pdf\UserChoice", press Edit --> Permissions, and change ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES to "Full Control".

THE CATCH:

As of Windows 10, you may receive a notification when doing this that "An app caused a problem with the default app setting for .pdf files, so it was reset to Microsoft Edge". This is Microsoft's attempt to stop apps from modifying the default programmatically like this.

The workaround is here: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-resetting-file-associations/

Download the REG file from that page and merge it with the registry first - it prevents Microsoft's apps from resetting the defaults. (back up the registry before making big changes!!)

Note that this is quite hacky and it's probably much better to just direct the user to the default programs dialog.

To do this instead:

```
public void ShowDefaultDialog(string path)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "rundll32.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "shell32,OpenAs_RunDLL " + path;
    proc.Start();
}
```

Where "path" is a the full path of a PDF file to open.

Comment: This code throws the Null exception.
 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf\UserChoice' is denied.
why it throws exception?

Comment: I can open my Project as admin mode and then run this code, But access denied error throws. please help me for this

Comment: It throws the exception because of the permissions on the registry value. To change this, open the registry editor (windows key + r, type "regedit", press enter), navigate to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf\UserChoice", go to the Edit menu --> permissions, click on "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" and tick the "Full Control" box. You'll have to do this on any machine where you want this code to run though.